# Show hint on each bar of each series TChart -Delphi

Tags: delphi, bar-chart, mouseevent, teechart

In my project I've got several TCharts with 2 series and 2 bars in each series.
[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zu2SX.png)

On each of them I need to show the value of the series bars on mouse hoovering over them.
I'm using onMouseMove event:

```
    procedure TfrmBoard.chartCountMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift:
        TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    var
      SeriesIndex  : Integer;
    begin
      with Tcontrol(Sender) do
      begin
        seriesIndex := (Sender as TChart).series[0].clicked(X,Y);
        ShowHint := SeriesIndex <> -1;
    
        if ShowHint  then
           Hint := FloatToStr((Sender as TChart).series[0].YValues.Value[seriesIndex]);
    
      end;

end;
```

This code shows the values of the first series in the chart, but not of the second.

If I add a loop, the event will show values of the second series only.

```
procedure TfrmBoard.chartCountMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift:
    TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  SeriesIndex  : Integer;
  i: Integer;
begin
  with Tcontrol(Sender) do
  begin
    for I := 0 to (Sender as TChart).SeriesCount - 1 do
    begin

    seriesIndex := (Sender as TChart).series[i].clicked(X,Y);
    ShowHint := SeriesIndex <> -1;

    if ShowHint  then
       Hint := FloatToStr((Sender as TChart).series[i].YValues.Value[seriesIndex]);
    end;

  end;

end;
```

Can somebody help how to show values for both series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to break loop when `ShowHint` becomes `True`, otherwise it might be overwritten with next `False` values

```
if ShowHint  then begin
   Hint := FloatToStr((Sender as TChart).series[i].YValues.Value[seriesIndex]);
   Break;
end;
```

By the way, does your `TChart` have event `OnMouseEnter` for **SeriesXX** objects?

Comment: Thanks, that works! I tried break before but that didn't work because I put it outside of showHint...